# How to create a simple EQ like AVAudioUnitEQ in AudioKit?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, audiokit, equalizer

I'm attempting to transition my audio project to utilize AudioKit. In my current setup, I employ a standard Apple node for equalization. Here's a snippet to provide context:

```
var engine = AVAudioEngine()
var eqNode = AVAudioUnitEQ()

engine.attach(eqNode)

func initEqualizer() {
    eqNode = AVAudioUnitEQ(numberOfBands: frequencies.count)
    eqNode.globalGain = 0
    for i in 0..<frequencies.count {
        eqNode.bands[i].frequency = Float(frequencies[i])
        eqNode.bands[i].gain = 0
        eqNode.bands[i].bypass = false
        eqNode.bands[i].filterType = .parametric
    }
}

eqNode.globalGain = eqSettings.generalGain
for i in 0..<frequencies.count {
    eqNode.bands[i].gain = values[i]
}
```

I had assumed that integrating ParametricEQ would be straightforward, but I've encountered challenges:

- The ParametricEQ appears to utilize different parameters and lacks a globalGain feature, which is essential for my setup.
- Despite reviewing AudioKit's cookbook examples, I haven't found a similar straightforward example of a simple equalizer.

It seems like I may need to develop a custom Equalizer class in AudioKit to replicate the functionality of my AVAudioUnitEQ. Am I on the right track, or is there something I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

Look into SoundPipeAudioKit, AudioKits extension library with Instruments and Effects.
There are several filters available, e.g. [EqualizerFilter](https://audiokit.io/SoundpipeAudioKit/documentation/soundpipeaudiokit/equalizerfilter).

Comment: Yea, I did and it uses totally different parameters and doesn’t works the same. Like what is bandwidth should be for each band? Where is general gain?

Comment: can you please provide a code sample of covering a simple EQ into this new? Since currently your answer doesn't helps at all, don't trying to be rude.. but it is like so..